# Pandas : update int Series with one or several 0

Tags: python, pandas, string, series

I've got a pandas Serie in a DF, like this one :

```
DF=pd.DataFrame([1,2,58,99,123,256],columns=["ID"])

    ID
0   1
1   2
2   58
3   99
4   123
5   256
```

I'm trying to modify "ID" column, in order to have something like this (always three characters, so one or two zeros for numbers with length<3) :

```
    ID
0   "001"
1   "002"
2   "058"
3   "099"
4   "123"
5   "256"
```

I tried to achieve this with a list comprenhension, astype(str), replace() and str.len(), like this :

```
DF["ID"]=[x.replace(x, i*"0"+x) for x,i in (DF["ID"].astype(str),int(DF[DF["ID"]].astype(str).len())-3)]
```

But then I had this Error

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([1, 2, 58, 99, 123, 256], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

How could I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to pass the values in the your 'ID' series as if it were a list of column labels.
There is a much simpler way of doing this using pandas apply and the str.rjust() method setting the width to 3 to pad the strings to 3 characters:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ID=[1,2,58,99,123,256]))

df['ID'] = df['ID'].apply(lambda x: str(x).rjust(3,'0'))
```

Outputs:

```
    ID
0   "001"
1   "002"
2   "058"
3   "099"
4   "123"
5   "256"
```

Answer (score 0):

you an use f-strings with formatting

```
DF['ID'] = DF['ID'].apply(lambda v: f'{v:03d}')
```

output (these are string btw)

```
    ID
0   001
1   002
2   058
3   099
4   123
5   256
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the most idiomatic way is:

```
>>> DF['ID'] = DF['ID'].astype(str).str.rjust(3, '0')                           
>>> DF                                                                          
    ID
0  001
1  002
2  058
3  099
4  123
5  256
```